# Application crashes in Xcode while trying to put an "UITableViewCell" method. Shows THREAD 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sigabrt

So i am trying to put an `UITableViewCell cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in my `ViewController.h` file. (I am trying to make a "todo-list" application with a few `viewControllers`). But when I execute the app into the iOS simulator, it crashes and gives me:

```
THREAD 1: signal SIGABRT.
```

And in the debug output shows me:

```
2014-05-24 16:12:38.657 Tarea[2107:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ee1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0178f3f6 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
3   Tarea                               0x00002dc4 -[ViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 180
4   UIKit                               0x0032611f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
5   UIKit                               0x003261f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
6   UIKit                               0x00307ece -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2428
7   UIKit                               0x0031c6a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
8   UIKit                               0x0029c964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157f82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
10  QuartzCore                          0x03c5945a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
11  QuartzCore                          0x03c4d244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
12  QuartzCore                          0x03c593a5 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
13  UIKit                               0x0035eae3 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
14  UIKit                               0x00274aa7 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
15  UIKit                               0x00273646 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
16  UIKit                               0x00273518 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
17  UIKit                               0x002735a0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
18  UIKit                               0x0027263a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
19  UIKit                               0x0027259c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
20  UIKit                               0x002732f3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
21  UIKit                               0x002768e6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
22  UIKit                               0x00350b77 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
23  UIKit                               0x0026c474 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 591
24  UIKit                               0x0026c5ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
25  UIKit                               0x0026c86b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
26  UIKit                               0x002773c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
27  UIKit                               0x00227bc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
28  UIKit                               0x0022c667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
29  UIKit                               0x00240f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
30  UIKit                               0x00241555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
31  UIKit                               0x0022e250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
32  GraphicsServices                    0x037e3f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
33  GraphicsServices                    0x037e3a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
34  CoreFoundation                      0x01769ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
35  CoreFoundation                      0x017699db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
36  CoreFoundation                      0x0179468c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
37  CoreFoundation                      0x017939d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
38  CoreFoundation                      0x017937eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
39  UIKit                               0x0022bd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
40  UIKit                               0x0022df9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
41  Tarea                               0x000039ad main + 141
42  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e35701 start + 1
43  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Using Breakpoints, it shows me that the problem is here:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *celda = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Celda"];

    TareaFenomenal *libro = [_libros objectAtIndex:1];

    UILabel *etiqueta = (UILabel *) [celda viewWithTag:42];
    etiqueta.text = libro.nombre;


    return celda;
}
```

it shows the problem in the second line.

i am starting to learn how to code, so please be patient with me.

Comment: looks like _libros is an empty array, or only contains an item at index 0

Answer (score 1):

The `objectAtIndex` is a zero-based index. The first object in an array has an index of `0`. The second object has an index of `1`. Thus `[_libros objectAtIndex:1]` means that you're trying to retrieve the second item in the `_libros` array.

The error message "index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]" informs you that while you're trying to retrieve the second item (i.e. the item with an index of `1`), the array only has one object in it (i.e. it has object(s) with indexes ranging from `0` to `0`; in other words, there is only one item in it and it has an index of `0`).

So the only question is whether you really meant to retrieve the first object (in which case you'd do `[_libros objectAtIndex:0]` or `[_libros firstObject]`). Or did you really mean to retrieve the second object and there was some reason the `_libros` array had fewer items in it than you expected (in which case, you should take another look at the code that populated `_libros`).